Jenkins Pipeline issue due to tag
created pipeline using jenkins, script is given.Tag gets created on qa and gets checked out on uat. facing the below error.
RC-20240708-0956
/tmp/jenkins6430156383955054035.sh: line 6: [[: RC-20240708-0956: value too great for base (error token is "0956")
If time is greater than 10, it gets check out, Otherwise it throws this error.
QA:
git tag -a   RC-$DATE || exit 1
git push origin RC-$DATE || exit 1
UAT:
git fetch --tags
git checkout $BRANCH || exit 1
i have tried putting "" arounf tags. still the same error.

For some reason it is treating your tag name as a math expression. Numbers that a prefixed with 0 are octal and cannot have 9 in them. When your time is past 10 it doesn't start with 0 anymore and everything works. I don't know if it works as expected though, because you are doing some math with your tag names, but that's a different concern.
